# how to modify the following table

Tags: tables

In the example below, you might see that I have a table:

I would like to change/introduce and understand the following:

1. How to change the column separator say to `\Rightarrow`. Normally one can do this by introducing `@{$\Rightarrow$}` when the columns
   are specified as `{cc}` etc. but in the "paragraph mode" as here,
   how is is done? In this case the implies sign (`\Rightarrow`) is
   shifted upwards.
2. How to make sure the numbering `(2)`, `(3)` etc of table rows is aligned with the main numbering (the top `(1)` earlier?
3. How to introduce an align environment in column 2 (commented out in
   the example)?

---

```
\documentclass[leqno,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Lecture 1}
\rhead{Handout 3}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem,array}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} %for proof 
\newtheorem*{mythm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{mydef}{Definition}
\title{\ul{Conditional Expectations in Bivariate Probability Distribution}}
\date{}
\newenvironment{mydescription}{%
   \renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\textbf{{##1}}}%
   \begin{description}%
}{%
   \end{description}%
}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{Myitemize}{%
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{{}}%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]}{\end{itemize}}

\maketitle

\newcommand{\myitem}{\stepcounter{enumi}\item[(\theenumi)]}%for enumerate with no. in brackets
\newcommand\litem[1]{\item{\bfseries {#1}}}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{definition} 
If the random vector $(X,Y)$ has joint \textbf{pdf} $f(x,y)$ with conditional \textbf{pdf} $g_{2}(y|x)$, and if $Z=h(X,Y)$ is a (single-valued) function of (X,Y). Then the conditional expectation of the random variable $Z$, given $X=x$ is 
\begin{equation}
E(Z|x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{h(x,y)g_{2}(y|x)dy}
\label{eq:}
\end{equation}
\end{definition}    

\begin{mydescription}
\item[Special cases] (a,b,c are constants; ($X^{*}=X-E(X); Y^{*}=Y-E(Y)$)\\
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}@{$\Rightarrow$}
                   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,leftmargin=*,series=mylist,label=(\arabic{enumi}),start=2]
    \item $Z=a+bX+cY$
    \end{enumerate} &
    \begin{Myitemize}
      \item abc %\begin{align*}E(Z|x)&=E(a|x)+b.E(X|x)+c.E(Y|x)\\&=a+bx+c.E(Y|x) \end{align*}
    \end{Myitemize}\\[-3ex]
    \begin{enumerate}[nosep,resume*=mylist]
      \item $Z=XY$
    \end{enumerate} &
    \begin{Myitemize}
      \item def
    \end{Myitemize}\\[-3ex]
    \begin{enumerate}[nosep,resume*=mylist]
      \item $Z=Y$
    \end{enumerate}&
    \begin{Myitemize}
      \item 123
    \end{Myitemize}\\[-3ex]
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep,resume*=mylist]
      \item $Z=(Y-\mu_{Y|X})^{2}$
    \end{enumerate} &
    \begin{Myitemize}
      \item 456
    \end{Myitemize}\\[-3ex]
        \begin{enumerate}[nosep,resume*=mylist]
      \item $Z=(Y-\mu_{Y})^{2}$
    \end{enumerate} &
    \begin{Myitemize}
      \item 789
    \end{Myitemize}\\[-3ex]
    \end{tabular}
\end{mydescription}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The last question is simple: `\\[-3ex]` means a line break, immediately followed by a negative vertical space of 3ex (`ex` is approximately the height of the letter x in the current font).

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks so much, finally I have grasped `ex` :-)

Comment: (4) It depends a bit on the details. The quick answer is 'yes' but the longer answer is that the results may or may not be what you want. Obviously non-paragraph column specs do just this. But you can also use other packages such as `tabularx` which allow you to use `X` to specify automatically-adjusted columns. For (1), what exactly is the problem with the `@` method here?

Comment: @cfr: Thanks very much indeed. Problem with the `@` method is that the column separators are shifted a bit upwards. I will modify the question

Comment: For point 1, you can use any separator you wish between any type of columns.But don't forget to write `@{${}\Rightarrow{}$}` (with both pairs of empty braces to ensure a correct spacing.

Comment: @Bernard:Thanks very much indeed. I'm afraid I still have output as here http://screencast.com/t/FfqtLsBn1U. Indeed, but given relations across the two columns, I wish to have the implies sign. Many thanks again

Comment: May be I'm completely mistaken, but I think you don't really need a tabular environment. It seems completely artificial. I'll propose another solution, based on amsmath in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing things, first defining a `\mycases` environment in the `definition` style of `amsthm`, and two ways of having your equations aligned on the left margin — one defining a `tabenum` counter that's increased each time a`\tabitem` command is called (and it can be cross-referenced); the other simply uses the`flalign` environment, and thus the numbering of equations follows the general numbering of equations in the document. The following code lets you compare both ways — actually three if the second column has aligned equations. I added a macro for the conditional expected value, heavily borrowed from §3.6 of the `mathtools` doc, thathas better spacing and delimiters that automatically adjust to the size of the argument (with the * version):

```
\documentclass[leqno,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Lecture 1}
\rhead{Handout 3}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm} %for proof
\newtheorem*{mythm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{mydef}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{mycases}{Special cases}
\title{\ul{Conditional Expectations in Bivariate Probability Distribution}}
\date{}
\author{}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\EV[1]{E}(){}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,}
#1}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{Myitemize}{%
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{{}}%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]}{\end{itemize}}

\maketitle

\newcommand{\myitem}{\stepcounter{enumi}\item[(\theenumi)]}%for enumerate with no. in brackets
\newcommand\litem[1]{\item{\bfseries {#1}}}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{mydef}
If the random vector $(X,Y)$ has joint \textbf{pdf} $f(x,y)$ with conditional \textbf{pdf} $g_{2}(y|x)$, and if $Z=h(X,Y)$ is a (single-valued) function of (X,Y). Then the conditional expectation of the random variable $Z$, given $X=x$ is
\begin{equation}
\EV{Z \given x} = =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{h(x,y)g_{2}(y|x)dy}
\label{eq:}
\end{equation}
\end{mydef}

\begin{mycases}
(a,b,c are constants; ($X^{*}=X-E(X); Y^{*}=Y-E(Y)$)\\
%

\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{1}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}(\thetabenum)}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\enspace}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash $}X <{$}
 !{{} $ \Rightarrow ${}} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\tabitem & Z=a+bX+cY & $ \begin{aligned}[t]\EV{Z \given x}&=\EV{a \given x}+b.\EV{X \given x}+c.\EV{Y \given x}\\&=a+bx+c.\EV{Y \given x} \end{aligned}$\\
\tabitem & Z=XY &def \\
\tabitem & Z=Y & 123 \\
\tabitem & Z=(Y-\mu_{Y|X})^{2} & 456 \\
\tabitem & Z=(Y-\mu_{Y})^{2} & 789
 \end{tabularx}

\begin{flalign}\label{cas}
    & Z=a+bX+cY & \Rightarrow\quad & \!\begin{aligned}[t]\EV{Z \given x}&=\EV{a \given x}+b.\EV{X \given x}+c.\EV{Y \given x} \\&= a+bx+c.\EV{Y \given x} \end{aligned} &\hphantom{Z=a+bX+cY\quad(2)} & \\
   & Z=XY & \Rightarrow\quad & \text{def} \\
 & Z = Y & \Rightarrow\quad & 123 \\
 & Z=(Y-\mu_{Y|X})^{2} &\Rightarrow\quad & 456 \\
 & Z=(Y-\mu_{Y})^{2} & \Rightarrow\quad & 789
\end{flalign}

\begin{flalign}\label{cas}
    & Z=a+bX+cY & \Rightarrow\quad & \!\begin{aligned}[t]\EV{Z \given x}&=\mathrlap{\EV{a \given x}+b.\EV{X \given x}+c.\EV{Y \given x}}\\&=\mathrlap{a+bx+c.\EV{Y \given x}} \end{aligned} &\hphantom{Z=a+bX+cY\quad(2)} & \\
   & Z=XY & \Rightarrow\quad & \text{def} \\
 & Z = Y & \Rightarrow\quad & 123 \\
 & Z=(Y-\mu_{Y|X})^{2} &\Rightarrow\quad & 456 \\
 & Z=(Y-\mu_{Y})^{2} & \Rightarrow\quad & 789
\end{flalign}
\end{mycases}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. And suppose instead of "abc" I need to introduce an `align` environment as in the commented out part in the MWE, how should I do it please?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora You should review the `amsmath` package [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for see the different options for align single or block of equations.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: That is easy with the `aligned` environment — we have 3 ways to do things now. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Bernard: Hi! Thanks for your answer. For some mysterious reason when I compile your solution I obtain 64 errors (pertaining to `flalign`). I'm still wondering what is the problem exactly...thanks

Comment: @Bernard: There seems to be a problem with the `\providecommand` as well, where the new command `given` is defined

Comment: Your code is broken up into two parts. additionally, please have a look at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17344334#17344334

Comment: Thanks to @Johannes_B: the command that breaks the code above is fixed as \providecommand\given{} 
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\EV}[1]{E(}{)}{\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,} #1}.

Comment: Sorry for this problem: I was aware that a line beginning with a % broke the code, and I hadn't re-read the display to check. @Johannes_B: Thanks for pointing me the problem. It's corrected now.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Arora: Sorry for not having answered before. I've just discovered you comment. Does the modified code (deleting the comment in the empty line) work for you now?

Comment: @Bernard: Yes it is fine now. Thanks very much indeed. Cheers!

Comment: @Bernard: I am trying to get a better understanding of latex thanks to your helpful answer. Could you please explain what is the necessity of using the \hphantom{} command in the context above?

Comment: It moves the second alignment (beginning with `\Rightarrow`) to the left by ~50 pt (half the `hphantom{…} width). Try without this \hphantom and compare. Anyway, it's just a suggestion to improve (in my opinion) the general look of the display.